# Memory Leak when using package slava:redis-livedata in Meteor js

Tags: meteor, redis

I hope anyone can help, I am using Meteor for a big app in production now, and I experience memory leaks when using slava:redis-livedata, the error logs shows

```
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I understand this happens when page is very loaded with subscriptions, has anyone made a workaround for achieving this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Memory leaks are very rare in node.js. Are you sure you don't just run out of memory naturally? Have you already increased the node.js memory limits?

Comment: No. I hadn't done it yet, I am running inside a docker container so I will check how to increase it properly in this scenario. Thanks